# WPF - How to make thickness be independent on scale?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I draw shapes programmatically, via the DrawingContext.
And I want shapes have a fixed thickness independent on the RenderTransform's scale.

Can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `DrawGeometry` method to draw your shapes as geometries. You could then apply the transform to their `Transform` property.

```
var transform = new ScaleTransform(...);
var ellipse = new EllipseGeometry();
...
ellipse.Transform = transform;
drawingContext.DrawGeometry(null, pen, ellipse);
```

You can even modify the transform after drawing the shapes.

Comment: I don't understand how can I make fixed thickness with this transform?
Also it would be good to make min thickness == 1px.

Comment: Set the `Thickness` property of the Pen that is passed to DrawGeometry. It won't change when the geometry is transformed.

Comment: I write ``line.Transform = new MatrixTransform();`` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Come on, did you set anything else than Identity as the MatrixTransform's Matrix?

Comment: I tried ``line.Transform = new ScaleTransform(1.01, 1.01);`` but and this doesn't  work.